# Draw Map using JTS API And PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, jts-topology-suite

I use PostgreSQL for storing data. I want to create map based on it using JTS. I want to create geometry object from list of rows. Such geometry object to used as draw polygon,point etc.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way (in my opinion) is to use [GeoTools](http://geotools.org), if you follow the [quickstart tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide.old/tutorial/quickstart/index.html) you will see how to draw the features of a shapefile on the screen using swing. Then all you need to do is change the input [datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) to use PostGIS (a simple change to the parameters) and you are done.

Comment: i don't want to use GeoTools .Because Created data Render In browser so   .any other Solution Jts create Geometry Object From  Geom Column of  Postgresql Database.

Comment: please edit your question to clarify what you want to do

Comment: i want just create geometry Object using  JTS API and those Geometry Comes From DataBase. Geometry Contains Lost of Rows....